# Resultset closed and I have no idea why

Tags: java, sqlite, resultset

I'll leave my code here. My problem resides in the line marked with `--> <--` where I get `java.sql.SQLException: ResultSet closed` and I can't find the reason why.

I've tried creating a different `Statement`, using `stat2` which works fine with the `ResultSet` right above this one, changing `stat4` to be a `PreparedStatement` instead, but nothing seems to work.

I've already found trouble with the previous `ResultSet` in this project, so I guess I don't really understand them very well.

Anyway, if someone can give me some tips about this I would appreciate it a lot.

```
public void asignarOficio(AsignacionesData pagina) throws SQLException {
    Statement stat1 = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rsObligados = stat1.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLA_OBLIGADOS + " WHERE " + OBLIGADOS_COL_ASIGNADO + " = 'NON'");
    //POR CADA ALUMNO/A EXISTENTE EN LA TABLA BUSCAREMOS UNA OFERTA DE TFG QUE ASIGNARLE
    while(rsObligados.next()) {
        //PARA SABER QUE OFERTA DEBEMOS ASIGNAR AL ALUMNOS, PRIMERO BUSCAMOS 
        //EL PROFESOR/A QUE (ESTANDO OBLIGADO/A) MENOS TFGS DIRIJA
        Statement stat2 = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rsMin = stat2.executeQuery("SELECT MIN("+ PROFESORES_COL_TFGS +") FROM " + TABLA_PROFESORES + " WHERE " + PROFESORES_COL_OBLIGA + " = 'SÍ'");
        int min = rsMin.getInt(1);
        System.out.println("min: " + min);
        rsMin.close();
        
        ResultSet rsProf = stat2.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLA_PROFESORES + " WHERE " + PROFESORES_COL_TFGS + " = '" + min + "'");
        String prof = rsProf.getString(2);
        System.out.println("prof: " + prof);
        rsProf.close();
        //UNA VEZ CONSEGUIDO EL NOMBRE DEL PROFESOR/A BUSCAMOS 
        //ENTRE LAS OFERTAS DISPONIBLES, UNA QUE DIRIJA ÉL/ELLA
        Statement stat4 = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rsOferta = stat4.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLA_OFERTAS + " WHERE " + OFERTAS_COL_TITOR + " = '" + prof + "' AND " + OFERTAS_COL_ASIGNADA + " = 'NON'");
        ------------>int idOfer = rsOferta.getInt(1);<--------------
        System.out.println(" idOfer = " + idOfer);
        int numOfer = rsOferta.getInt(2);
        String tutOfer = rsOferta.getString(4);
        String  cotutOfer = rsOferta.getString(5);
        rsOferta.close();
        //AL TENER YA LOCALIZADO EL TFG SOLO QUEDA HACER LOS UPDATES
        //PERTINENTES EN LAS TABLAS DE LA BD
        Statement stat3 = con.createStatement();
        stat3.executeUpdate("UPDATE " + TABLA_OFERTAS + " SET " + OFERTAS_COL_ASIGNADA + " = 'OB' WHERE " + OFERTAS_COL_ID + " = '" + idOfer + "'");
        stat3.executeUpdate("UPDATE " + TABLA_OBLIGADOS + " SET " + OBLIGADOS_COL_ASIGNADO + " = 'SÍ' WHERE " + OBLIGADOS_COL_ID + " = '" + rsObligados.getInt(1) + "'");
        stat3.executeUpdate("UPDATE " + TABLA_OBLIGADOS + " SET " + OBLIGADOS_COL_SELECCION + " = " + numOfer + " WHERE " + OBLIGADOS_COL_ID + " = '" + rsObligados.getInt(1) + "'");
        if (cotutOfer.equals("")) {
            stat3.executeUpdate("UPDATE " + TABLA_PROFESORES + " SET " + PROFESORES_COL_TFGS + " = " + PROFESORES_COL_TFGS + " + 1 WHERE " + PROFESORES_COL_NOMBRE + " = '" + tutOfer + "'");
        } else {
            stat3.executeUpdate("UPDATE " + TABLA_PROFESORES + " SET " + PROFESORES_COL_TFGS + " = " + PROFESORES_COL_TFGS + " + 0.5 WHERE " + PROFESORES_COL_NOMBRE + " = '" + tutOfer + "'");
            stat3.executeUpdate("UPDATE " + TABLA_PROFESORES + " SET " + PROFESORES_COL_TFGS + " = " + PROFESORES_COL_TFGS + " + 0.5 WHERE " + PROFESORES_COL_NOMBRE + " = '" + cotutOfer + "'");
        }
    }
}
```

Here I provide de Log in case someone wants take a look at it:

`prof: Formella, Arno`

```
sept. 09, 2021 6:13:05 P. M. UI.AsignacionesData btn_AsignarActionPerformed


SEVERE: null

java.sql.SQLException: ResultSet closed


at org.sqlite.core.CoreResultSet.checkOpen(CoreResultSet.java:76)
at org.sqlite.core.CoreResultSet.markCol(CoreResultSet.java:103)
at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3ResultSet.getInt(JDBC3ResultSet.java:395)
at CORE.DBManager.asignarOficio(DBManager.java:754)
at UI.AsignacionesData.btn_AsignarActionPerformed(AsignacionesData.java:209)
at UI.AsignacionesData$1.actionPerformed(AsignacionesData.java:74)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1967)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2308)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:279)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6636)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3342)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6401)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2263)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5012)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2321)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4844)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4919)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4548)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4489)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2307)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2764)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4844)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:772)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:743)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

I'm not able to put the log as "code" in the editor of StackOverflow, sorry for the inconvenience that may cause.

Comment: Could there be a problem that you are getting null from the query and then trying to use a method on it?

Comment: @DenisStojkovićStole that scenario would result in a `NullPointerException` somewhere in the stack trace.

Comment: What database are you using? SQLite right? If so, verify that the ResultSet is not empty because otherwise it may be closed by SQLite.

Comment: Tip: [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) syntax.

Comment: @FranciscoTena You were right, I misscalculated the response from the database and the `ResultSet` was empty.  **For anyone using SQLite DB with the same problem check if the `ResultSet`is empty with `if(ResultSet.next()` so you don't have this problem**

Comment: Initially a result set is positioned **before** the first row, you always need to call `next()` to position it on the first (or subsequent) row (or to detect that there are no rows), and so on.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel That's not how it works, as in the code it self it's shown how I do the exact same thing and the variables "int" and "prof" are stored perfectly. I'm using SQLite and the `ResultSet` is just closed when it finds no rows to match the `SELECT` query

Comment: When accessing a result set, you will always need to call `next()` (or one of the other navigation methods) and check its return value before accessing a column, that is how the JDBC API is defined. That SQLite also immediately closes an empty result set is technically a violation of the specification, but given checking `next()` still works, that is something that you can work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are reusing Statements here:

```
        Statement stat2 = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rsMin = stat2.executeQuery("SELECT MIN("+ PROFESORES_COL_TFGS +") FROM " + TABLA_PROFESORES + " WHERE " + PROFESORES_COL_OBLIGA + " = 'SÍ'");
        int min = rsMin.getInt(1);
        System.out.println("min: " + min);
        rsMin.close();
        
        ResultSet rsProf = stat2.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLA_PROFESORES + " WHERE " + PROFESORES_COL_TFGS + " = '" + min + "'");
        String prof = rsProf.getString(2);
        System.out.println("prof: " + prof);
```

Try to create a Statement (or even better [PreparedStatments](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)) for each query.

Also please check if the ResultSets are not empty, SQLite may close the ResultSet when it's empty.

Comment: It was empty as you said, thank you very much.

Comment: Please mark the answer as the correct answer so other users can benefit also. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes that apparently SQLite closes de `ResultSet` automatically when the query finds no row to match.
Be sure to check your `ResultSet` with `if(ResultSet.next())` it will only go through the `if` if the `ResultSet` has something inside.